# Increase python script speed

Tags: arcpy, performance, cursor

```
for row1 in cursor1:

    if row1[0] != None:
        num3=row1[0].upper()
        custx=row1[4] 
        custy=row1[5]
        num2=row1[8]
        try:
            m=re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0])
            num=m.group()
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        mycust=row1[9].replace(","," ") 
        mycust=mycust.replace("&"," ")
        custlist=mycust.split()
        custlist=[x.upper() for x in custlist]
        custlist=[i for i in custlist if len(i) > 1]

        try:

            t=re.search(r"[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)?(\s[A-Za-z]+)?(\s[A-Za-z]+)?",row1[8])
            num1=t.group()    
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        if len([item for item in addrlist if item[0]==num3 and re.search(r"^[0-9]*\s",num3) and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<2500]) == 1:
            t=[item for item in addrlist if item[0]==num3 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<2500]
            row1[1]=t[0][1] 
            row1[2]=t[0][2] 
            row1[3]=t[0][3] 
            row1[6]="Match1"
            row1[7]=int(harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,t[0][2],t[0][3]))
            row1[10]=t[0][4]
            row1[11]=t[0][0]
            row1[13]=t[0][5]

        elif len([item for item in propadd if item[0]==num2 and re.search(r"^[0-9]*\s",num3) and myparclist(custlist,item[1])>0 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<3000]) == 1: #ensure the proper address starts with a number      
            q=[item for item in propadd if item[0]==num2 and myparclist(custlist,item[1])>0 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<3000]             
            row1[1]=q[0][1] 
            row1[2]=q[0][2] 
            row1[3]=q[0][3]
            row1[6]="Match2"
            row1[7]=int(harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,q[0][2],q[0][3]))
            row1[10]=q[0][0]
            row1[11]=q[0][4]
            row1[13]=q[0][5]

        elif len([item for item in propadd if item[0]==num2 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500]) == 1:
            v=[item for item in propadd if item[0]==num2 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500]
            row1[1]=v[0][1] 
            row1[2]=v[0][2] 
            row1[3]=v[0][3] 
            row1[6]="Match3"
            row1[7]=int(harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,v[0][2],v[0][3]))
            row1[10]=v[0][0]
            row1[11]=v[0][4]
            row1[13]=v[0][5]

        elif len([item for item in numlist if item[0]==num and myparclist(custlist,item[2])>0 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[3],item[4])<600]) == 1:
            z=[item for item in numlist if item[0]==num and myparclist(custlist,item[2])>0 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[3],item[4])<600]
            row1[1]=z[0][2] 
            row1[2]=z[0][3] 
            row1[3]=z[0][4] 
            row1[6]="Match4"
            row1[7]=int(harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,z[0][3],z[0][4]))
            row1[10]=z[0][5]
            row1[11]=z[0][1]
            row1[13]=z[0][6]

        elif len([item for item in numlist if item[0]==num and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[3],item[4])<150]) == 1:                                             
            z1= [item for item in numlist if item[0]==num and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[3],item[4])<150]
            row1[1]=z1[0][2] 
            row1[2]=z1[0][3] 
            row1[3]=z1[0][4] 
            row1[6]="Match5"
            row1[7]=int(harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,z1[0][3],z1[0][4]))
            row1[10]=z1[0][5]
            row1[11]=z1[0][1]
            row1[13]=z1[0][6]

        elif len([myitem for myitem in snamelist if myitem[0]==num1 and myparclist(custlist,myitem[2])>0 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,myitem[3],myitem[4])<150]) == 1:
            j=[myitem for myitem in snamelist if myitem[0]==num1 and myparclist(custlist,myitem[2])>0 and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,myitem[3],myitem[4])<150]
            row1[1]=j[0][2] 
            row1[2]=j[0][3] 
            row1[3]=j[0][4] 
            row1[6]="Match6"
            row1[7]=int(harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,j[0][3],j[0][4]))
            row1[10]=j[0][1]
            row1[11]=j[0][5]
            row1[13]=j[0][6]

        cursor1.updateRow(row1)  
del row1
del cursor1
```

Comment: If you can take the time to do a little cleanup, you should submit bits of this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. I've had to use and change a very similar script made by an previous coworker dealing with a PostGIS DB, and e.g. `row1[13]=z1[0][6]` just _smells_ ; even with comments and a lot of care it's just so easy to make a mistake and not realize why for hours!

Comment: Also, as @Matej said in his answer, consider using a real database instead of shapefiles. Just as an example, that very similar script I was talking about went from 15 minutes to less than a second by converting all Python `for` loops into indexed SQL joins, so it can be done! Good luck :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person who asked the question had to remove all parts of it and is unable to delete the question themselves.

Comment: I'll talk to the other moderators about whether we can delete the question, because doing so will deny its answerer 60 reputation points which seems unfair.

Comment: @ketar: A shame you weren't able to keep the code here, it didn't seem as if it was giving away much. At least on this point look at [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). And yes, I meant that for joins ; others might disagree with me, but if you are able to drop down to raw SQL instead of Python, the speedup can be immense with the proper indexes.

Comment: If the user wants the question deleted, they should have that right, regardless of whether or not someone "gets points" for answering the question.  Imagine if you were in this users position.

Comment: @RyanDalton I wish it were that simple but I have discussed this with other moderators here and with the community team, as well as advising the user offline about their options which they exercised overnight.  I urge anyone asking questions and posting codes to be certain that they are not divulging proprietary information as they agreed not to do so when joining the site and accepting its terms of service.

Comment: I think all proprietary information has now been redacted and purged from the revisions of this question as per the requested edit that you performed overnight.  For future reference there is a procedure for circumstances such as these documented at Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260507/what-can-i-do-if-i-post-confidential-information

Answer (score 6):

From the posted code is unclear where the myparclist is coming from. I presume that you are running a searchCursor within the updateCursor.

You may avoid a searchCursor by joining the tables and only running the updateCursor. Or, if you have customer locations, you may want to perform a spatial join instead.

Few more ideas:

- move the data into a filegeodatabase and add indices to the fields that are used by the searchCursor
- you may try creating a dictionary upfront for parcel data and then retrieve them quickly within the updateCursor.
- do some profiling to determine which parts are taking the longest.

Comment: Only moving the data into fgdb will most likely not make much of a difference. Why don't you simply join/spatially join the tables?